# Cypress - screenshots

Tags: cypress

I'm using cypress version 4.0.2
I'm having trouble configuring screenshot support in cypress. In case of an error, the screenshots directory is not created and there is no dump in it.

I took the steps:

a) accordance with https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Screenshots
I added the "screenshotsFolder" parameter to cypress.json: "cypress / screenshots", and "trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true,

b) according with https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api.html#Arguments - in cypress / support I created the file index.js adding in it:
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults ({
   screenshotOnRunFailure: true
})

I run tests and although 2 of them have an error, the directory and screenshots were not created.

Comment: Are you calling, `cy.screenshot()`. anywhere? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot.html#Syntax

Answer (score 1):

cy.screenshot() is only needed for manual screenshot. Screenshots by default are taken.
I have the same issue in 4.4.1. I havent changed any settings, but my screenshots are no longer being captured on errors.